# LeaveCriticalSection causing the app crash

Tags: c++, crash, critical-section

Our legacy C++ app crashing at LeaveCriticalSection.
The application is a single threaded and am not sure for what reasons critical section is used since it is a legacy code.
Still trying to find out the reasons of crash.
The crash window just says unhandled exception.
The app only crashes in release mode

Comment: In your debugger, enable "break on throw", and see what exception is being thrown that isn't being handled.

Comment: It only crashes in release mode

Comment: If this is legacy code, presumably it worked at some point and stopped recently. In this case, it seems probable that the code contains Undefined Behavior and you are now seeing the consequences of that manifest. If that is the case, the cause of the problem may be anywhere in the code and it might be unrelated to where you see a crash. Consider getting your hands on some sanitizers to see if the error can be found by code analysis tools.

Comment: In addition to François Andrieux's excellent suggestion, you can build release mode with debugging information.  Alternatively, you can add logging information and instrument your code.  You could add a try-catch-rethrow block in the suspect area of the code.

Comment: Critical section is even needed here for single threaded app? Should it be simply removed and tested thoroughly?